# PSet 3 - CS50 - Binary Search Implementation

Tags: c, cs50

This is PSET 3 from the CS50 course on edX.org.

I have been struggling with this problem set for a very long time; particularly, I cannot get the binarySearch function to work. I keep getting a segmentation fault and I can't figure out how to deal with it. I have spent a lot of time thinking through this and I just don't see it.

Here is my code. Can someone point out conceptually where I am going askew here? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

bool binarySearch(int value, int values[], int min, int max)
{
    bool answer = false; 

    if (max < min)
    {
        answer = false;
    }

    else if (values[max] == value)
    {
        answer = true;
    }

    else if (values[min] == value)
    {
        answer = true;
    }

    else
    {
        int midPoint = (max + min) / 2;

        if (values[midPoint] == value)
        {
            answer = true; 
        }

        else if (values[midPoint] > value)
        {
            answer = binarySearch(value, values, min, midPoint);
        }

        else
        {
            answer = binarySearch(value, values, midPoint, max);
        }
     }

    return answer;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int value = 34;

    int values[] = {11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,1010};

    int max = sizeof(values) / sizeof(int);

    if (binarySearch(value, values, 0, max - 1))
    {
        printf("Found needle!\n");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Did not find needle\n");
    }
}
```

I keep getting a segmentation fault when the value I am searching for is not in the array.

Comment: It is late, and my brain is shutting down.  In reviewing your code, perhaps there is a problem with the line 'int max = sizeof(values) / sizeof(int);'  You may wish to 'printf("max[%d]\n", max);' and verify that it prints what you expect (ie: 10 ?).

Comment: Why don't you use a simple iteration with `while`? It is simpler, faster and safer than recursion...

Comment: @Mahonri - I did test it that way before; it comes up with the correct size of max.

Comment: @CiaPan, I can't conceptualize how a while loop would be coded...

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Iterative

Comment: The concept is: `while( the array part is too long ) { divide it into halves and continue on the proper half } then if the part has only one element test if that is the sought one;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should change you code to:

```
 else
    {   
        int midPoint = (max + min) / 2;

        if (values[midPoint] == value)
        {
            answer = true; 
        }

        else if (values[midPoint] > value)
        {
            answer = binarySearch(value, values, min, midPoint-1); // not midPoint
        }

        else
        {
            answer = binarySearch(value, values, midPoint+1, max); //not midPoint
        }
     }
```

Comment: this worked! You won't believe how long I've spent on this. I have learned a lot along the way though. Can you explain to me, however, why it is necessary to add midPoint - 1 and midPoint + 1. I tried tracing this out on paper and it is not making sense to me.

Comment: @user3237895 Try to follow your program with a sheet of paper and a pencil while searching for `7` in a single-item array with the only value of `3`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here

```
if (max < min)
```

Eventually, `max` will equal `min`, but nothing in the code forces `max` to become less than `min`.  Hence, the function will recurse forever, if the specified value is not in the array.